# AngularJS : Is it Possible to load two different html with two different routers(one for each .html) in one single application?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I'm having two HTML files -> `index.html` and `start.html`

So far I was developing an app(a small application) in a single dimensional thought where `index.html`  serves as the main page and `app-route` serves as the main router for the application. Now we're creating a bigger application like a `.com` site and integrating the previous application with the this(`.com`).

We do not want to disturb the smaller application code and we're developing a .com site which is a different html(`start.html`) and a different router (`dot-com-route.js`). Now, whenever I try to load http://localhost/myApp/app/#/start.html, its loading the index.html with app-route.js?

Is it always like, angular application looks for `index.html` file to execute?

This is my app-route.js:

```
smartPrintApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/smart_print_landing/smart-print-landing.html'
      }).
      when('/index.html', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/smart_print_landing/smart-print-landing.html'
      })
  }
]);
```

Comment: I believe you have put in you angular code that on route (`when('/')`) it uses `index.html`. Can you post your JS code?

Comment: @vucko I've updated the app-route.js for you

Comment: When you hit your http://localhost/myApp/app/#/start.html browser will load some HTML(depends on your backend) this should be your index.html then angular will check the hash and will load a template you specified in templateUrl and it will inject it into index.html wherever you have ng-view attribute. If you want start.html to be served instead of index.html then you need to change this on server. Sorry if i didn't understand what you want exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're attempting to open http://localhost/myApp/app/#/start.html the part of the URL that the server will actually try to serve is http://localhost/myApp/app/. After the server has sent the browser the requested page AngularJS will come into play and read the part after the has (#) to determine which route to use. Since you have not included a specific HTML file in the part that the server is reading the server will serve the HTML file that has been set as the default (I assume from the behaviour you are getting that this is index.html).

So in order to get your second landing page you should use http://localhost/myApp/app/start.html/#/ (or something similar depending on the route you wish to access) as the URL.

Comment: The url that worked for me was -> http://localhost/dotcom/app/start.html#/
Previously I was trying http://localhost/dotcom/app/#/start.html which is wrong.